# How to show link and description in ListView from RSS feed?

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I want to show both title and description which is parsed from an RSS feed website in the list view. now it can show only the title. i already done with the fetching of description. all i need to show the description below the title. how can i do that ?

This is my RssAdapter.java

```
package com.example.jaison.newsclient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<RssItem> items;
private final Context context;

public RssAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());


  //need to show getdescription also


return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
}
}
```

this is my rss_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Rssitem.java

```
package com.example.jaison.newsclient;


public class RssItem {

private final String title;
private final String link;
private final String description;

public RssItem(String title, String link,String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.description=description;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

}
```

and another code here

```
package com.example.jaison.newsclient;

import android.util.Xml;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

public class PcWorldRssParser {

private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION= "description";
private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";
private static final String TAG_RSS = "rss";

// We don't use namespaces
private final String ns = null;

public List<RssItem> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}

private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, TAG_RSS);
    String title = null;
    String link = null;
    String description=null;
    List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();


    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals(TAG_TITLE)) {
            title = readTitle(parser);

        } else if (name.equals(TAG_LINK)) {
            link = readLink(parser);



        }
        else if (name.equals(TAG_DESCRIPTION)) {
            description = readDescription(parser);



        }
        if (title != null && link != null && description != null) {
            RssItem item = new RssItem(title, link,description);
            items.add(item);
            title = null;
            link = null;
        }
    }
    return items;
}

private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, TAG_LINK);
    String link = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, TAG_LINK);
    return link;
}

private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, TAG_TITLE);
    String title = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, TAG_TITLE);
    return title;
}
private String readDescription(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, TAG_DESCRIPTION);
    String description = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, TAG_DESCRIPTION);
    return description;
}

// For the tags title and link, extract their text values.
private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: in rss_item layout create description textview and set the description to that in the same way how your setting the title

Comment: included rss_item in question . can you please make changes and write it as answer ?@KingofMasses

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rss_item should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="discription"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in getview it should be like this

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            holder.itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.itemDescription.setText(items.get(position).getDescription())




return convertView;
}
```

Your view holder should be like this

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemDescription;
}
```

Comment: but it is showing one heading and another description

Comment: means ? Is it not showing the correct description for the Item ?

Comment: what is not working. can you elaborate more , so that we can help

Comment: actually i am planing to create a news app which will show title and description . after adding your answer it is showing title and description . but description is different showing some other description

Comment: The problem is the way how you stored the title & description. there is no problem with the view / adapter codes.. If you have doubts then print the values in Log and check

Comment: if the title is the first one then the description is from the second one

Comment: i did not get you, i am a new in android

Comment: How your getting the RSS feed data and storing into the items list ? check that

Comment: check my question , i have added the code , is there any problm ?

Comment: that is the not one which i am talking about.. From where your RSS data coming and how your adding into RSSItem list  ? API call

Comment: please see my question again

Comment: y u are not making description= null  here if (title != null && link != null && description != null) {
            RssItem item = new RssItem(title, link,description);
            items.add(item);
            title = null;
            link = null;
        }
add that also and check

Comment: is that the problem ?

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome :)